# Extension method is not recognized, what is wrong?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public string Index()
        {
            // ERROR call extension method here
            return GetMemberName();
        }
    }

    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static string GetMemberName(this Controller caller, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
        {
            return caller.GetType().FullName + "." + memberName;
        }
    }
}
```

My extension method is not recognized, what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefix the call with `this`:

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Store/

    public string Index()
    {
        return this.GetMemberName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my ghost, we must explicitly specify the `this`. :-)

Comment: Good catch...  I couldn't see what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Do you know the reason why we must explicitly specify the `this`?

Comment: Because extension methods only work with an instance and this pointed to an instance...

Comment: @Kai: But why must it be explicitly specified? :-) We call it inside the method of a class being extended, so `this` should be negligible.

Comment: No, in your case it is a little bit confusing. But, think in another way. Extenstion methods only work with instances, like Class1 class1 = new Class1(); class1.MyExtenstionMethod(). Without this, it is only Class1.MyExtenstionMethod().